# Getting an error in the second call of js function that contains ajax

Tags: javascript

I'M SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH TYPING, i hope you understand me.

This is the problem. I have a JS function `changeHierarchy()` that contains an ajax function that reload a table. The general HTML of the page is structured with some radius (outside from the table) that deppending which is selected the table reloads on different ways and it works ok, but the problem is when i try to reload this table pressing some button that is part from the table, when i press that button once is works ok, but when i press it secondly i get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` on my browser.

I explain what referred to the different radius and buttons because i use de same JS function in two cases.
I sure that the problem is because the buttons are inside the table.

My only solution was call the JS function and then another function that reload my page like this:

```
onclick='changeHierarchy(<? echo $voluntary?>,2),reload();'
```

It work perfect but i don't want to reload de hole page.

I don't understand so much but i imagine that could exist a way to refresh something related to the button for replace calling the function reload.

Thank you so much if you can help me.

Comment: If you want *code* help you should probably show some code.

Comment: To elaborate: what's the ajax function, what's the button click code? The location of a button inside a table shouldn't make any difference to the functionality (unless you want it to)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my ignorance, i only had a little error on the string that return the tbody from the table, the problem was that PHP variable that is the parameter on the button function was written incorrectly so when i excecuted the ajax function, the parameter wasn't correctly and that was the error.

Next time i promise you that i will write some code if not you can't help me.